# DataFrame value startswith

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```
        Datum   Zeit                                     Event
0  14.11.2016  13:00   Veröffentlichung des 9-Monats-Berichtes
1  14.03.2017  13:00            Telefonkonferenz für Analysten
2  14.03.2017  13:00            Telefonkonferenz für Analysten
3  27.04.2017  14:00              Ordentliche Hauptversammlung
4  03.05.2017  14:00                         Dividendenzahlung
5  15.05.2017  14:00                    Bericht zum 1. Quartal
6  14.08.2017  14:00           Telefonkonferenz für Investoren
7  14.08.2017  14:00            Telefonkonferenz für Analysten
8  14.08.2017  14:00  Veröffentlichung des Halbjahresberichtes
```

I am looking for the dates of quarterly reports here ("Bericht" in good old German).
I can select the row via

```
df.loc[df["Event"].str.startswith("Bericht"), "Datum"]
```

which returns a `Series` object like

```
5    15.05.2017
Name: Datum, dtype: object
```

However, I only want to have the date - am I overcomplicating things here?

Comment: if you just want the scalar value then you need to access it: `df.loc[df["Event"].str.startswith("Bericht"), "Datum"][0]`

Comment: Sorry try `df.loc[df["Event"].str.startswith("Bericht"), "Datum"].values[0] `

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default a `Series` is returned when accessing a specific column and row in a `DataFrame` if you want a scalar value then you can access the array element using `.values` to return `np` array and then indexing into it:

```
In [101]:
df.loc[df["Event"].str.startswith("Bericht"), "Datum"].values[0]

Out[101]:
'15.05.2017'
```

For safety you should check whether your selection yields any results prior to indexing into it, otherwise you get a `KeyError`:

```
if len(df.loc[df["Event"].str.startswith("Bericht"), "Datum"]) > 0:
   return df.loc[df["Event"].str.startswith("Bericht"), "Datum"].values[0]
```

Comment: You can but it's more lines, both attempts are valid

Answer (score 1):

You are doing well. If you only want to have the date, you can do:

```
df.loc[df["Event"].str.startswith("Bericht"), "Datum"].values
```

This returns a list of dates.